# jquery cannot get div to show using this selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am querying the Twitch API for a list of users in my database, to see if they are online.

I am essentially listing them all, with "display: none" and then unhiding if online:

```
  $('.online_list').each(function (index) {
      var tnick = $(this).data('tnick');
    $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?client_id={:twitch_key}&channel="+tnick+"", function(a) {
      if (a["streams"].length > 0)
      {
        alert(tnick);
        $(this).show();
        console.log(index + ": " + $( this ).text());
      }
    });
  });
```

In my testing, the `alert(tnick)` works perfectly, so I know it's running. The problem is `$(this).show();` just isn't working.

Here's example HTML:

```
<div class="online_list" data-tnick="test" style="display: none;">test:<a href="https://www.twitch.tv/test">Twitch</a> <span>(Online)</span></div>
<div class="online_list" data-tnick="test2" style="display: none;">test2:<a href="https://www.twitch.tv/test2">Twitch</a> <span>(Online)</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is the current scope object!

to fix your code you can do the following:

```
$('.online_list').each(function (index) {
    var $that = $(this); // create a temp var that
    var tnick = $that.data('tnick');
    $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?client_id={:twitch_key}&channel="+tnick+"", function(a) {
      if (a && a["streams"] && a["streams"].length > 0) {
        alert(tnick);
        $that.show(); // use that instead of this
        console.log(index + ": " + $that.text());
      }
    });
  });
```

Check out this resource for more information on scope & this: http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/

Comment: Yup, that was it exactly. I'm not sure how sane my code is, as we could have a list of like 100 people here, which ends up as 100 API calls to Twitch, but it works and it seems to be quite fast. Any suggestions on improving? Thanks for the additional link.

Comment: if condition could result in a `undefined error`.. the rest lgtm

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Also, like @djxak suggests, you can use the `element` parameter of the callback, that is more simple and clean in my opinion.

The @djxak suggests:

```
  $('.online_list').each(function (index, element) {
      //... (scope1 code)
      $.getJSON("", function(a) {
          //... (scope2 code)
          $(element).show();
      });
  });
```

My approach:

```
  $('.online_list').each(function (index) {
      //... (scope1 code)
      var $current = $(this);
      $.getJSON("", function(a) {
         //... (scope2 code)
        $current.show();
      });
  });
```

Info about each function and `element` parameter in jQuery docs: https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function

Comment: Or you can use second argument of [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)  function's callback - `element`. This is a DOM element, so you can do `$(element).show()`.

Comment: @djxak I think your approach is better, because is more simple and clean, why don't you explain it in a new answer?

Comment: because it is practically the same. `this` and `element` is same DOM object in this context. So your answer is correct. Feel free to add info from my comment to your answer if you want.